# HTML Page Loads To iframe?

Tags: html, css, iframe, position

I have an iframe link from a game I have hosted on a site called Scirra. I took the embed code and it is positioned at the bottom of my page. The strange and annoying this is that once the page is opened, the page loads up and shoots straight down to the div where the iframe is. Anyone have an idea on how to fix this?

```
  <iframe src="http://static1.scirra.net/arcade/games/4778/play" width="700" height="460" style="width:700px;height:460px;border:0;margin:0;padding:0;" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"  title="Captain Galactica and the SpiderCats" ></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `window.scrollTo(0, 0);` on window load.

or add `onload = 'window.scrollTo(0, 0)'` to your body tag.

Comment: just about works. scrolls to the bottom for a few seconds and then goes to the top. an improvement either way, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<body onload="window.location.hash = '#divname';">
```

where `#divname` should be the id of the first element of your page